# Flask SQLAlchemy exist statement

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

This is my query

```
exist = db.session.query((exists().where(CreateUser.email == email) & (CreateUser.password == password))).scalar()
```

But I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound

My semantic is, it should check if the email and password exist from the table but I get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put brackets around whereclause

```
exist = db.session.query((exists().where( (CreateUser.email == email) & (CreateUser.password == password) ))).scalar()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exists()` function returns a boolean. If you want to return a single row, just do this:

```
session.query(User).filter(User.email == email).filter(User.password == password).first()
```

Comment: I want to return a boolean like if the record exist go to dashboard else display error

Comment: Oh I think if I pass a variable to it like   exist = session.query(User).filter(User.email == email).filter(User.password == password).first() , all I need do is to say if exist and not if exist == true